# In jQuery Mobile, how do I make text inputs go full screen while editing if the phone is tilted to landscape?

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, textinput

I have a text input in jQuery Mobile. I'm also using PhoneGap to package it up as an application. The problem, however, is that, when I tilt the phone to landscape view, I the text editing isn't going full screen. How do I make it do that?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My App</title>
    <script src="phonegap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqm/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqm/jquery.mobile.structure.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqm/jquery.mobile.theme.min.css" />
    <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jqm/jquery.mobile.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="myapp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">

        <div data-role="header" data-id="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c">
            <h1 style="text-align:left; margin: 10px;">My App</h1>
            <a href="settings.html" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn-right" style="margin:1px;">Settings</a>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">
            <p>
                <label for="basic">Text Input:</label>
                <input type="text" name="status" id="status" value=""  />
            </p>
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer" data-id="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html" data-icon="plus" class="ui-disabled">New Log</a></li>
                    <li><a href="logs.html" data-icon="refresh">Logs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.html" data-icon="info">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /navbar -->
        </div><!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

This is a good example of what I'm trying to say. This is the text input when the messaging app is in portrait mode.

[image]

Now when I tilt the phone to landscape, the text input box will become full screen like this:

[image]

That's what I want to achieve.

Comment: Erm, I don't see how that will be of any help but there you go.

Comment: Actually I meant your header...

Comment: Updated with the full index.html page.

Comment: ok good :) I'll post an answer... wait a sec :P

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your header:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'/>
```

So your header would look like something like this:

```
<head>
    <title>My App</title>

<meta name='viewport' content='minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no'/>

    <script src="phonegap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqm/jquery.mobile.theme.min.css" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqm/jquery.mobile.structure.min.css" />

    <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jqm/jquery.mobile.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="myapp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Have a try. This should normally work.

Comment: I tried, unfortunately, it didn't seem to be any different than before. I also updated my question with screenshots.

Comment: Oh... :O... wait I'll test you code in my environment :). Btw, what version of Android are you using?

Comment: I'm on ICS 4.0.4 :) PhoneGap v2.1.0, jQuery Mobile v1.2.0, jQuery v1.8.2.

Comment: Ok :). Hey mate could you try the code (change the header only) I re-edited? I am really not sure, are you using a custom theme?